# Proper usage of navigation component with view pager2 and nested navigation

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to build the following view structure/ navigation using ViewPager2 + FragmentStateAdapter + navigation component.

Preconditions: Single activity architecture, with one navigation graph

**1. Fragment A** holds a view pager. View pager uses FragmentStateAdapter.

**2. Fragment B** is instantiated via FragmentStateAdapter ("lives" in view pager).

**3. Fragment C** - should be navigated to from Fragment B. --> This is where the problem is.

---

### Approach 1 : ViewPager2 + FragmentStateAdapter + navigation declared from Fragment B

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.abc.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.abc.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/to_fragmentC"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentC" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:name="com.abc.FragmentC"
        android:label="FragmentC" />
```

FragmentB executes:

```
 FragmentBDirections
            .toFragmentC()
            .let { findNavController().navigate(it) }
```

Result :

```
App crash
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.abc:id/to_fragmentC is unknown to this NavController
```

---

### Approach 2 : ViewPager2 + FragmentStateAdapter + navigation declared from Fragment A

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.abc.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/to_fragmentC"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentC" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.abc.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:name="com.abc.FragmentC"
        android:label="FragmentC" />
```

FragmentB executes:

```
 FragmentADirections
            .toFragmentC()
            .let { findNavController().navigate(it) }
```

Result:

```
App navigates to FragmentC, but when i hit the back button , it crashes with :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:36)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(FragmentStateAdapter.java:132)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapterInternal(RecyclerView.java:1209)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerView.java:1161)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(ViewPager2.java:461)
        at com.abc.FragmentA.viewCreated(FragmentA.kt:69)
```

---

### Approach 3 : ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter (deprecated) + navigation declared from Fragment B

The same result as approach 1.

---

### Approach 4 : ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter (deprecated) + navigation declared from Fragment A

This one actually works. Also, the navigation back works fine.

The problem here is that:

- Navigation has to be defined for every parent fragment of FragmentB -> not so scaleable
- Usage of the adapter that is deprecated

If anybody knows some elegant solution to this problem, I would be very glad for any hints.

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem where i have NavGraph -> Fragment A which has ( View pager )  i have to navigate to fragment B from View pager ( Fragment 1 | Fragment 2 ) do post the solution if you get any i would do the same.

Comment: Approach 2 is working perfectly in my case.  The issue might be with viewpager not with navigation

Comment: How you initialized  FragmentStateAdapter? Are you getting FragmentStateAdapter instance from Dagger? The problem exists when you initialize with dagger

Comment: @nabeel I have the same crash log with approach 2. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Karthik please post code

Comment: @nabeel NVM, I fixed it! Lazy initialisation of adapter caused the issue. Not sure how lazy initialisation was the culprit.

Comment: it was also my case, had to remove the lazy{} instantiation of the adapter.
So:

`val adapter by lazy { MyAdapter() }`

to

`var adapter: MyAdapter? = null`. And instantiate it in onCreate or onViewCreated, i dont remember the method name by hearth :)

Comment: My fragment extends a base fragment. i don't have OnCreateView in the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare Fragment B as a destination in your graph, because you never use NavController to navigate to it. Instead of using an action, you can just use a **destination id** to implement navigation in Fragment B, like `findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentC)`. The `findNavController` method will find the parent fragment's navController to execute the navigation.

Comment: This is great, but how can it done while passing the arguments?

Comment: Passing the arguments by Bundle.
For example:
    
   `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", "value");
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentC, bundle);`

Answer (score 0):

### **General idea**

You can define a `Channel` in your ViewModel to handle the UI events.

Let's see how we can achieve this:

1. define your `viewModel`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class OrderViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {
    
    private val orderEventChannel = Channel<OrderEvent>()
    val orderEvent = orderEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    ...

    fun onInvoiceClicked(invoice: Invoice) = viewModelScope.launch {
        orderEventChannel.send(OrderEvent.NavigateToOrderDetailsFragment(invoice))
    }

    sealed class OrderEvent{
        data class NavigateToOrderDetailsFragment(val invoice: Invoice) : OrderEvent()
    }
}
```

2. Initial viewModel by `activityViewModels` and listen to the `Channel` in Fragment that contains `viewPager2` view:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OrdersFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_orders) {
    private val viewModel: OrderViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        ...
        
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.orderEvent.collect { event ->
                when(event){
                    is OrderViewModel.OrderEvent.NavigateToOrderDetailsFragment -> {
                        findNavController().navigate(
                            OrdersFragmentDirections.actionOrdersFragmentToOrderDetailsFragment(event.invoice)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Now in all `Fragment` that bind in `viewPager` initial viewModel by `activityViewModels` and call `onInvoiceClicked()` function:

```
class InProgressViewPagerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_in_progress_view_pager){
    private val viewModel: OrderViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
        binding.invoice.setOnClickListener{
           viewModel.onInvoiceClicked(invoice)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you found a solution to your problem but this is how I did it in my app (this is similar to what you describe for solution 4)

I have an application that has a main fragment (HomeFragment) which contains a bottom tab bar which shows four different fragments.

At any point while using the application the user can log in/log out (this is a flow that contains 4 fragments in it) answer a questionnaire (2 fragments) show settings (one fragment) or take a picture (1 fragment)

I have declared my home view model like so:

```
class HomeViewModel(app:Application):AndroidViewModel(app), HomeParent {
}


intefrace HomeParent { //this contains all the actions that can be executed, like showLogin, showQuestions etc etc
    fun ShowLogin()
 
}
```

Inside the HomeFragment I initialize the pager like so:

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment(), KoinComponent {
    private val vm by sharedViewModel<HomeViewModel>()

    private val pager by lazy { binding.pager }  //I just use view bindings you can do it with findviewbyid
    private val adapter by lazy { HomePageAdapter(this) }

    
    override fun initView(state:Bundle?) { //this is run before oncreate finishes
         pager.setPageTransformer(this::pageAnimation) //this is just to animate transitions
    }

    override fun setUpListeners() {  //this is run after oncreate finishes
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this::navigationItemSelected) //this does stuff and sends it to vm
        pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(pagerChangeCallback)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        pager.adapter = adapter
        (vm.state.value as? HomeState.Default)?.let { //I'm using mvi, this basically holds the current position in the pager
            pager.setCurrentItem(it.position.position, false)
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        pager.adapter = null //I don't remember why I did this, I gues
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        pager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(pagerChangeCallback)
    }

}
```

the actual adapter looks like this:

```
class HomePageAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    override fun getItemCount() = 4

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> Fragment1()
            1 -> Fragment2()
            2 -> Fragment3()
            3 -> Fragment4()
            else -> throw Throwable("Invalid position $position")
        }
    }
}
```

each of those fragments is created like so:

```
class Fragment1 :Fragment(),
    private val home : HomeParent by sharedViewModel<HomeViewModel>()
    override val vm: Fragment1ViewModel by viewModel { parametersOf(home) }
```

as you can see I pass the home view model as a parameter to each of the tabs inside home

then each fragment can do something like

```
home.ShowLogin()
```

this will send the message to HomeViewModel which will in turn send the message to HomeFragment and it will call something like

```
findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.logIn())
```

so as you can see Fragment1/2/3/4 are outside of the whole navigation process, and HomeFragment contains all the actions that will be performed

I hope I explained it correctly, if anyone has any questions or need clarifications let me know